# What is WCHAN and PC in adb shell Android?

Tags: android, linux, performance, memory-management

Whenever WCHAN/PC reaches  the value `ffffffff f6ef1f04`, my app is crashing in Android.
How can I solve this problem?

```
root@android:/ # ps | grep org.*
USER PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS   PRIO  NICE  RTPRI SCHED   WCHAN  PC     NAME

u0_a71    11656 263   1213852 227856 ffffffff f6ef1f04 S               ***
```

Comment: Wait channel and program counter. Your app does not appear to be crashing -- if it were, there wouldn't be a process entry. Are you unable to attach a debugger?

Comment: App is not crashing , but its hangs.after few seconds,getting popup message "App isn't responding. Do you want to close it? ". In background process is running,program counter value gets stopped @ f75bff04. what would be the reason ?